# Página para cada usuário criado no banco de dados

Tags: php, html5, banco-de-dados

Minha dúvida rapidamente explicada: Tenho um banco de dados com 20 usuários cadastrados. O layout da página de cada usuário já está definida. Cada usuário pode mudar apenas seu nome, colocar sua foto em um campo já definido e contar um pouco de si. Assim que ele se logar, como mando ele para a sua página? Exemplo "pv.com.br/nomedousuario" Grato.

Comment: se alguém digitar na barra de endereços `pv.com.br/nomedousuario` vai ter acesso a página?

Comment: O meu problema é que eu já tenho uma página de perfil padrão chamada perfil.php, pra colocar ela em formato de cada usuário é que fica dificil pra mim na hora de chamar tipo "pv.com.br/perfil.php se pegar pelo id ficaria perfil1.php?

Comment: Eu quero dizer o seguinte: o usuario `fulano` faz o login e é direcionado para `pv.com.br/fulano.php`. A minha pergunta é: se outro usuário acessar a pagina pelo link `pv.com.br/fulano.php` vai ter acesso a essa página?

Comment: Essa sua pergunta me fez fazer uma pagina de login que redireciona para a pagina do usuário e que funciona assim: se o login estiver correto ele acessa a pagina dele. Se ele copiar o endereço dessa pagina e abrir em nova aba ou nova página não vai acessar a pagina, nem ele nem ninguém, somente fazendo novo login. Veja funcionando ( login: leo senha: 123 )  http://kithomepage.com/sos/login_key.php

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo o problema é que o cara não pode nem refresh na página por causa da one-time key. De qq forma, você pode usar essa idéia e atualizar a chave em todos os links quando for usar na prática, ai o cara é obrigado a manter 1 aba só (e se abrir o link em nova aba, a velha não navega mais). Uma outra maneira de fazer isso é usar um misto de JS e por um window.name, coisa que o link não propaga pra outra aba.

Comment: @Bacco, cada usuário só tem uma pagina!.

Comment: Eu ja tinha entendido, só complementei como usar essa idéia para ter mais de uma, e mesmo assim manter na mesma aba. Pra uma só nem precisava da chave, bastaria anotar na $_SESSION que ele já acessou e não deixar mais. (pq essa sua, se der F5 ele volta pro login, da mesma forma)

Comment: @bacco, hahaha, tinha esquecido das sessions. Mas de qq forma surgiu uma nova idéia  `você pode usar essa idéia e atualizar a chave em todos os links quando for usar na prática ....`

Comment: É o conceito de nonce (number once), a cada transação você atualiza um token, para evitar duplicação de credenciais. Isso é usado em muitos sistemas (no chat do Telegram, nos certificados do Let's encrypt, eu mesmo uso no meu sistema de atualização remota de software)

Comment: Efeito prático: pode ser que alguém copie 100% do HD de um cliente meu, anote o serial da máquina, etc, que na 1a atualização, uma das maquinas vai estar com o nonce errado. A partir daí, eu sei que uma das duas não é a original (pq quando uma atualizar, o nonce muda, ai a segunda máquina vai reproduzir o numero velho) - mas isso nao é nem pra evitar pirataria, e sim pra evitar que 2 maquinas atualizem um DB remoto, por exemplo, com ID errado. Pode acontecer uma cópia legitima num cliente, sem intenção de pirataria, se for um técnico desavisado, e eu tenho que saber pra garantir consistência.

Comment: Em PHP você pode fazer coisa similar renovando o ID da session. Se pegar o cookie e copiar pra outro browser, o primeiro que acessar um link mantem a session, o segundo já se perde. E pode usar token no URL como vc fez, mas ai voltamos pro começo da conversa: só uma aba sobreviverá. Como diria nosso amigo aqui, só pode haver um! -> http://midia.gruposinos.com.br/_midias/png/2016/07/18/highlander-1601069.png

Comment: só pode haver um https://lidiapereira.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/10.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente isso:

```
// ... lógica do login ...

header('Location: /'.$nomedousuario);
die();
```

- Sanitize os dados para ter certeza que `$nomedousuário` não tem caracteres especiais. Se tiver, vai precisar usar algo assim:

  ```
  header('Location: /'.urlencode($nomedousuario));
  die();
  ```
- Sempre depois de usar um redirecionamento deste tipo, use o `die();` para garantir que nada mais da página seja processado e enviado para o cliente. Já vi sistemas que serviam coisas indevidas por falta desse `die()` (o desenvolvedor não percebeu que estava enviando dados confidenciais, justamente porque o redirecionamento ocorria, mas bastava desligar o suporte a *redirect* do *browser* para ver a página)
- A especificação do cabeçalho `Location:` pedia o URL completo, incluindo protocolo e nome de domínio. Depois houve uma RFC "afrouxando" o requisito, mas sempre que possível, passe o caminho completo (o PHP tem variáveis para isso, em `$_SERVER`).